# Не получается расшифровать сообщение, не ясен метод

Tags: криптография, криптоаналитика

Имеется сообщение, зашифрованное. Каждый символ заменялся на одно и то же двузначное число. Пробелы, буквы, числа. Разные символы заменялись конечно разными двузначными числами.

Построил таблицу, посчитал каждое вхождение числа в строке, однако частота использования букв русского алфавита не помогла. Пытался расшифровать, по методу дешифрования простого шифра тоже не вышло.

Шифр прикладываю:

```
17 51 42 33 42 34 24 13 23 45 27 14 33 50 18 27 50 51 42 18 49 13 23 45 31 33 14 35 
35 13 45 35 33 50 22 15 29 13 42 27 45 18 13 39 17 12 42 27 17 39 45 29 17 45 29 27 
17 33 24 50 49 45 26 41 45 13 29 31 14 18 27 13 45 29 45 26 37 45 51 13 18 17 29 45 
41 32 45 39 50 24 14 27 27 51 49 45 17 22 33 13 27 24 15 42 45 22 50 12 42 27 15 45 
40 13 22 33 17 24 50 33 14 27 42 45 24 13 45 35 17 42 40 34 45 37 26 45 13 29 31 14 
18 27 13 27 51 49 45 17 27 35 33 13 29 12 42 24 17 45 32 41 45 13 29 31 14 18 27 13
```

Буду рад любому совету или попытке помочь, возможно я неправильно начал,либо где-то ошибся, но это первый и последний вариант который пришел в голову.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67259/discussion-between-hasmikgaryaka-and-lokengarvel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый используемый символ - `45`, и это пробел. Если мы поставим его, получим максимально реалистичную расстановку слов:

```
......... ............. ...... ......... ......... .. ....... .. ....... . .. ..... .. ........ ........ ...... ........... .. ..... .. .......... .......... .. .......
```

Наивно было бы полагать, что на таком небольшом тексте мы получим близкую к общему случаю частотность букв. Очень часто используемых слов как артикли `a/the` в английском языке у нас нет, поэтому отталкиваться не от чего.

Пойдем другим путем, возьмем самое длинное слово, оно на втором месте:

```
27 14 33 50 18 27 50 51 42 18 49 13 23
```

Символы `27`, `50`, `18` повторяются по 2 раза. Я взял словарь на `100,000` слов, и попробовал найти слова, с точно такими же повторениями букв. Нашлось 2 слова, смысл одного был непонятен, второе - `туристический`. Учитывая возможные падежи, возьмем слово без окончания: `туристическ`.

Добавим эти буквы в словарь, и посмотрим что получилось:

```
.чере.... туристическ.. .ру... .ри....ет с....ет.. .. .т.р.ик .. ...уст. . .. ч.с.. .. .и.уттчк ..р.т..е .и.ет. ...р..ируте .. ..е.. .. ...уст.тчк .т.р...е.. .. ...уст.
```

Используя словарь снова, можно увидеть, что на место первого слова подходит только что-то связанное с очередью. Добавим буквы `очеред` в словарь. Получаем:

```
очеред... туристическ.. .ру... .ри....ет с..о.ето. .о .тор.ик .. ...уст. . .. ч.со. .. .и.уттчк о.р.т..е .и.ет. ...ро.ируте .. .ое.д .. ...уст.тчк от.р...е.о .. ...уст.
```

Интересная картина вот здесь:

```
.о .тор.ик
[29]o [29]тор[24]ик
```

Два слова начинают с одной буквы, очевидно, что здесь `во вторник`:

```
очередн.. туристическ.. .ру... .ри..в.ет с..о.ето. во вторник .. .в.уст. в .. ч.сов .. .инуттчк о.р.тн.е .и.ет. ...ронируте н. .ое.д .. .в.уст.тчк от.р.в.ено .. .в.уст.
```

Теперь:

```
очередн[13][23] = очередная
туристическ[13][23] = туристическая
ч[13]сов = часов
```

После добавления букв в словарь:

```
очередная туристическая .ру..а .ри..вает са.о.ето. во вторник .. ав.уста в .. часов .. .инуттчк о.ратн.е .и.ет. .а.ронируте на .ое.д .. ав.устатчк от.рав.ено .. ав.уста
```

Дальше:

```
ав[31]уста = августа
гру[35][35]а = группа
отправ[12]ено = отправлено
пое[40]д = поезд
са[39]олето[39] = самолетом

очередная туристическая группа при..вает самолетом во вторник .. августа в .. часов .. минуттчк о.ратн.е .илет. за.ронируте на поезд .. августатчк отправлено .. августа

очередная туристическая группа прибывает самолетом во вторник [26][41] августа в [26][37] часов [41][32] минуттчк обратные билеты забронируте на поезд [37][26] августатчк отправлено [32][41] августа
```

Напоследок наверное нужно применить логику относительно чисел в датах/часах/минутах.